# SignalR How to determine if a client is still connected using IUserIdProvider

Tags: signalr

I have seen examples that manually keep track of users that are connected but is there a way to determine if a client is connected when using IUserIdProvider?

Answer (score 0):

`IUserIdProvider` interface allows you to specify how will SignalR assign user id to connection based on request. It doesn't have any direct support for monitoring if user is online.

To monitor online presence, you have to handle `OnConnected`, `OnDisconnected` and `OnReconnected` events in hub and store information about users in some storage (for example static class, database, etc.). Example can be found here: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections#inmemory

Comment: should handle manually!  those events are not reliable!  e.g. with 1 connection, disconnect can fire twice, or onreconnected can be fired without firing disconnect! or 1 user fires 2 connection. something like that!